# this api script for a app for a site i made is not working

Tags: c#, api

I need help with this

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace kbam_.API
{
    class filea
    {
        public static string filea(string url) //this code right here
        {
            string contents;
            var wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
            contents = wc.DownloadString(url);

        }


    }
}
```

and yes I am authorized by kesbook uk to use this I'm the owner so I can use what I want http://kesbook.cf/autho

Comment: Doesn't work how?   Dropping code with no explanation or an error message makes it unlikely to get an answer.  We're not mind readers.

Comment: your methode does not return a string.

Answer (score -1):

If you are querying a a RESTful API I would suggest using the [Restsharp](http://restsharp.org/) nugget package, it is much easier to use.